# In RDi, how do I run a debug with UPDPROD(*YES)?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rational-developer-for-i

In RDi,

- right-clicked on the program to debug,
- selected "Debug or Code Coverage"
- then "Set Service Entry Point"

Then started the program from a command line in another session.

RDi confirms 'Debug' perspective switch. However, I didn't get an option to start debug with update production files = *yes, so I got a DBGP0003E message.

Checking thru the joblog the root cause appears to be:

> Member myfile cannot be opened while UPDPROD(*NO)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Preferences (Window-->Preferences)

Run/Debug-->IBM i Debug

Make sure Update production files is checked.

[image]